# swift editor placeholder in source file error

Tags: swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

//ekran ilk yüklendiğinde yapılacak işlemler
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
//-------------------------------------------
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
//Tableview data source için
    //tableview satır sayısı
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 5
    }
    //------
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: <#T##IndexPath#>)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Tablolama yaptım bu arada canberkin amk"
        return cell
    }
//--------------------------------------------------

}
```

I take error on this code =
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: <#T##IndexPath#>)

Comment: Rebuild it and run again. Sometimes compiler don't updates the errors and warnings.

Comment: I solved the problem thank you guys. I wrote indexPath. not IndexPath.